# top output to narrow in cron

Tags: email, bash, curses

I'm trying to send an email through cron to know what processes are hogging my server. It works fine but the resulting email is too narrow and I need to know more about the process.

This is the script I'm using (stole it from here: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/server-usage/create-server-load-monitoring-bash-script):

```
#!/bin/bash
trigger=10.00
load=`cat /proc/loadavg | awk '{print $1}'`
response=`echo | awk -v T=$trigger -v L=$load 'BEGIN{if ( L > T){ print "greater"}}'`

if [[ $response = "greater" ]]
then
top -cSbn 1 | head -14 | tail -8 | mail -s"High load on server - [ $load ]" myemail@domain.com
fi
```

The resulting email is something like:

```
   PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND

 810809 root      20   0 20700  13m 3032 R   50  0.0   0:00.40 /prod/process-nam
 810802 root      20   0 20700  13m 3032 R   48  0.0   0:00.39 /prod/process-nam
 810808 root      20   0 20708  13m 3032 S   48  0.0   0:00.35 /prod/process-nam
 810803 root      20   0 20708  13m 3032 S   46  0.0   0:00.39 /prod/process-nam
 810810 root      20   0 20168  13m 3028 R   46  0.0   0:00.33 /prod/process-nam
 318723 www-data  20   0  146m 131m 3320 R   45  0.4  67:27.96 /home/server/pr
 810800 root      20   0 20704  13m 3032 S   45  0.0   0:00.39 /prod/process-nam
```

As you can see, the whole path is missing. 
But if i run the script from bash, it works, sending an email wide enough.

Is it a ncurses issue? Pipe mail issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Sven but my output for top is this:

```
# top -w
top: unknown argument 'w'
```

I guess you have a more recent version.
But you sent me in right direction(+1 for you): I changed my script to export the number on columns and now I have full output:

```
#!/bin/bash

trigger=15.00

load=`cat /proc/loadavg | awk '{print $1}'`

response=`echo | awk -v T=$trigger -v L=$load 'BEGIN{if ( L > T){ print "greater"}}'`

if [[ $response = "greater" ]]
then
#sar -q | mail -s"High load on server - [ $load ]" recipient@YourDomain.com
export COLUMNS=512
top -cSbn 1 | head -14 | tail -14 | mail -s"High load on server YODA - [ $load ]" quinhentos@queo.pt
fi
```

Comment: keepers on the realm, should I mark my answer as corrected?

Answer (score 8):

Use the `-w` switch for `top`.

```
   -w  :Output-width-override as:  -w [ number ]
        In  'Batch'  mode,  when  used without an argument top
        will format output using the COLUMNS= and LINES= envi‐
        ronment  variables,  if set.  Otherwise, width will be
        fixed at the maximum 512 columns.  With  an  argument,
        output width can be decreased or increased (up to 512)
        but the number of rows is considered unlimited.

        In normal display mode, when used without an  argument
        top  will  attempt to format output using the COLUMNS=
        and LINES= environment variables,  if  set.   With  an
        argument,  output  width  can  only  be decreased, not
        increased.  Whether using environment variables or  an
        argument with -w, when not in 'Batch' mode actual ter‐
        minal dimensions can never be exceeded.

        Note: Without the use  of  this  command-line  option,
        output  width is always based on the terminal at which
        top was invoked whether or not in 'Batch' mode.
```